# Getting a hash value of a binary file with python by md5, trying to weed out duplicates

Tags: python, file, md5

*The issue:* file name will result in a different hash value even if content of file is the same

---

Found the issue where the bug was in the MD5 buffer. We needed to declare a new hasher for each file. It was updating, the stream from the previous hash before. Uploaded a working version, will clear out all your duplicate files.

I'm trying to find all duplicate files under my directory, and delete all duplicate files (by their hash value) and leave one unique file left over.

I'm opening up files from a directory with `rb` and using md5 to get the hexdigest of each file but I find that files with a different name will hash out different values even though the content of the file is the same. This is true when trying to hash sound files, maybe because there is ID3 headers that are different based on the file name of the sound clip.

Is there a way to verify the integrity of each file's content without consideration of the file name?

Here I have posted my little personal script http://pastebin.com/YZYXKMpt

**Results:** Same hash values. Different :(

```
>>> md5("C:\\Users\\c\\Documents\\Test\\06 Liar Liar.mp3")
'f9c50701d728c87cd959e8b7c6e7ebb2'
>>> md5("C:\\Users\\c\\Documents\\Test\\06 Liar Liar - Copy.mp3")
'f9c50701d728c87cd959e8b7c6e7ebb2'

>>> sha1("C:\\Users\\c\\Documents\\Test\\06 Liar Liar - Copy.mp3")
'68dcad808ab68e6b1f8610d21e92944ceb45086f'
>>> sha1("C:\\Users\\c\\Documents\\Test\\06 Liar Liar.mp3")
'68dcad808ab68e6b1f8610d21e92944ceb45086f''

{'C:\\Users\\c\\Documents\\Test\\06 Liar Liar.mp3': 'c7c8c7f9791804d3e1951bebb5d1494025da458c', 
'C:\\Users\\c\\Documents\\Test\\06 Liar Liar - Copy.mp3': '64097f07a8c40488a74fb98a4b9e83d7e7885f6c', 
'C:\\Users\\c\\Documents\\Test\\06 Liar Liar - Copy (2).mp3': '68dcad808ab68e6b1f8610d21e92944ceb45086f'}
```

Comment: Why all the downvotes? This seems like a legit, though misinformed, question

Comment: I don't understand either. I would like to know how hashes work on files.

Comment: The filename should not be having any effect whatsoever on the MD5 digest of the file contents.  Can you post a sample file (without infringing on any copyrights, of course) that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield You are correct, the file name should not have an effect on the hash values what so ever. My error was using the same hasher object to do every file hash. Since I have been feeding hasher with bytes (updating everytime), the next file would continue off the stream of bytes from the last file.

Comment: @czl - Are you saying that you have solved the problem raised by this question? If so, please either post your solution and accept it, or delete the question. That way people don't come here trying to provide a solution for the next 10 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hasher should be re-instantiated for each unique file. Should not use one md5 hash object to do every hash or else the hash streams will build up variables from the previous file hash value.

```
for i,files_in_folder in enumerate(all_files_in_all_folders):
    # Incase files are too large for memory, we will read 1mb increments
    block_size = 2**20
    # Iterate through each folder to read each file
    for each_file in files_in_folder:
        # Hasher will get the hash value of each files in this folder
        hasher = hashlib.md5()
    # Now i'm opening every file to get it's hash value below
        with open(subfolder_paths[i][0]+"\\"+each_file, 'rb') as to_check_for_duplicates:
            # We send large files bits by bits to the hasher so we can read larger files
            while True:
                file_buffer = to_check_for_duplicates.read(block_size)
                # If we have reached the end of the file, we break out
                if not file_buffer:
                    break
                # Updating the hasher everytime we feed more bytes
                hasher.update(file_buffer)
        # Effectivley putting each hash hex value into a dictionary with the filepath and key
        the_hash_dictionary[subfolder_paths[i][0]+"\\"+each_file] = hasher.hexdigest()
```